# React Native Android: How do you figure out which key was used to sign your app?

Tags: gradle, google-play, react-native, google-play-services

I'm trying to upload a build of my app to the Google Play Console and it's telling me the app signed with the wrong key. It says the SHA1 of the key that should be used, and the SHA1 of the key that I'm actually using. How do I find where the key I'm using is, so that I can replace it with the correct one?